# java object to javascript object websockets

Tags: java, javascript

is there a way to know the class name of an object in javascript that is coming from java using websockets. the classes are sent as json.

in javascript i parse the message as:

```
var chatMessage = JSON.parse(frame.body);
```

and in java i send the object as:

```
//chatMessage is ChatMessage object;
template.convertAndSend("/topic/chat", chatMessage);
```

the constructor function in javascript returns "object" only. how can i get "ChatMessage" class in javascript? or should make a ChatMessage object in javascript then use the instanceof operator?

the data comes from the server is json:

```
[{"sender":"user","message":"test"},{"sender":"user","message":"asd"},{"sender":"user","message":"test2"}]
```

console.log(chatMessage) output:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Comment: what does the data look like when you `console.log(chatMessage)`

Comment: Okay. There is now way to know what the class is without explicitly adding it to the data being sent to the client. How you do that depends on the Java code

Comment: so my last resort is to add the class name and add it to the data being sent to websockets?

Comment: From what I can tell by the code provided, yes